# Operator not applicable to this operand type

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

i have this situation:

```
type
  TWheel = record
  private type
    TWheelEnum = (whBA, whCA, whFI, whGE, whMI, whNA, whPA, whRM, whRN,
      whTO, whVE);
  var
    FWheelEnum: TWheelEnum;
  public
    class operator Implicit(const Value: string): TWheel;
    class operator Implicit(const Value: TWheel): string;
  end;
```

with:

```
var
 awheel, bwheel: twheel;
begin
  try
    awheel := 'PA';
    bwheel := 'PA';
    if awheel = bwheel then writeln ('pippo');
end.
```

When i run it turn me this error:

```
E2015 Operator not applicable to this operand type
```

i have solved writing:

```
if awheel = string(bwheel) then writeln ('pippo');
```

but is possible solve it without add string(...)? In a first moment i have thinked something as:

```
class operator Implicit(const Value: TWheel): Twheel;
```

but compiler turn me error, telling that only one TWheel type is accepted. So i wanted know if there is a solution for it, or if i need use conversion type with string(...)?
Thanks very much.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to define an `Equal` operator:

```
class operator Equal(const a, b: TWheel): Boolean;
```

I guess the implementation should be:

```
class operator TWheel.Equal(const a, b: TWheel): Boolean;
begin
  Result := a.FWheelEnum=b.FWheelEnum;
end;
```

You will probably also want to implement the `NotEqual` operator.

```
class operator TWheel.NotEqual(const a, b: TWheel): Boolean;
begin
  Result := a.FWheelEnum<>b.FWheelEnum;//could write not (a=b) instead
end;
```

The definition of these operators is, in fact, enough for the compiler to accept equality comparison with mixed `TWheel` and `string` operands.

The full list of operators is provided in the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Operator_Overloading_%28Delphi%29) and it's well worth a read once in a while to reacquaint yourself with what is available in way of operator overloading.

Comment: Yes, too, is possible that i need too of it. But for it, i have thinked to solve as:   "if not ( awheel = bwheel ) then" is same? or there some other solution for it? Thanks.